# Is there any way in NetBeans (for PHP) 7.x to work on remote server without downloading files?

Tags: php, netbeans, remote-access

Before using NetBeans I have used AptanaStudio, whitch was 'reading' files from the server, and wasn't downloading all of them in order to be able to show the folders/files structure. Then only when opened, the file is downloaded and on save, updated to server.

NetBeans, from what I can see has to doenload all files locally then sincronize/update server.

If I install a framework (for ecommerce, for example), I have to download afterwords thousands of files.

Please, tell me how can I avoid (if possible) this phase (downloading all) and work "Aptana Style".

Comment: It seems dangerous to update files on a production server as you go along. Are you sure you cannot use a version control system and just not include files that are not relevant i.e. these "commerce" files that you are never going to edit?

Comment: Usualy is a domain/subdomain used for developement, and it is online in order to provide acces to the customer..

Comment: Curious to know if you ever found an answer to this - currently looking to do the same thing myself

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't. Eclipse handles ftp connections on which you can build a project, but it takes years to go through files in order to be able to "know" about classes and then give you hints and stuff (which was the reason I wanted this in the first place). If you don't need this hinting "service" which an IDE offers, you can just use Aptana, Dreamweaver and even Notepad++ which are able to work with projects through ftp connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file to the server using ctrl + u (If my memory is good). So chaining ctlr + s and ctrl + u would do the same with a few more buttons.

And I think you can even bind both actions in one keybinding, but not sure.